# Background timer function in WIndows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, timer, background, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I'm developing windows phone 8.1 Application. I have timer function that works perfect in foreground. I need to send report every 30 seconds when Panic button is on.

Here is My Timer Class,

```
 public void Start_timer()
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(00, 0, 30);
        bool enabled = timer.IsEnabled;
        timer.Start();
    }

 async void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        // string which collects data. 
       URL_log_string = device_id_string + "," + UTCdatetime + "," + lng + "," + lat + "," + speed + "," + heading + "," + alt + "," + "," + battery_level + "," + accuracy + "," + 1 + "," + "," + 0; 

       //Locally log storage 
       Log_Class_Object.Save_Data_in_Log("Panic Sent ", URL_log_string);
       URL_log_string = "";

    }
```

my background Class is to implement background task.

```
class Task_Class
{

    public sealed class ExampleBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

          //

            _deferral.Complete();
        }

    public static async Task<BackgroundTaskRegistration> RegisterBackgroundTask(String taskEntryPoint, String name, IBackgroundTrigger trigger, IBackgroundCondition condition)
       {
           foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
           {
               task.Value.Unregister(true);
           }
           await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
           var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
           builder.Name = name;
           builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
           builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
           //var ret = builder.Register();

           BackgroundTaskRegistration related_task = builder.Register();

           return related_task;
       }

   }
}
```

Here is My xmlmanifest screen shot.

[image]

I don't have idea how to call this timer class in background. Cooperation in this regard will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use DispatcherTimer in background task

Use ThreadPoolTimer

```
    TimerElapsedHandler handler=function;
        ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(handler, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

 async  private void function(ThreadPoolTimer timer)
        {
            URL_log_string = device_id_string + "," + UTCdatetime + "," + lng + "," + lat + "," + speed + "," + heading + "," + alt + "," + "," + battery_level + "," + accuracy + "," + 1 + "," + "," + 0; 

   //Locally log storage 
   Log_Class_Object.Save_Data_in_Log("Panic Sent ", URL_log_string);
   URL_log_string = "";

        }
```

Comment: this will work for background too bro.? like if this timer is running then when app is in background / suspended ?

Comment: can you please update your answer according to my first timer function. like how this will implement in real time. thanks

Comment: Please check. Is it fine? When you call ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(handler, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)); timer will automatically starts. So write that line appropriately

Comment: Bro this works perfect in foreground. I have implemented that function. this also does not work in background. when app is in background then threadpooltimer stopped. while when user is again active then timer starts.

Comment: this should need to paste in background task class. would you please explain this bit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105902/discussion-between-user2354187-and-arsal).

Comment: TimerElapsedHandler handler=function;
        ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(handler, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)); add this code at the end of the Run Method or wherever  you want your timer to start in background task

Comment: ok Thanks. I note one thing in this.. I'm not able to stop this threadpool timer.  how to stop this?

Comment: You will get instance of the timer in handler right. Just call timer.cancel(). Thats it.